# Fail to active conda in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, conda

Testing the azure devops pipeline on a python project build by conda

```
jobs:
  - job: pre_build_setup
    displayName: Pre Build Setup
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'
    steps:
      - bash: echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin"
        displayName: Add conda to PATH

  - job: build_environment
    displayName: Build Environment
    dependsOn: pre_build_setup
    steps:
      - script: conda env create --file environment.yml --name build_env
        displayName: Create Anaconda environment
      - script: conda env list
        displayName:  environment installation verification

  - job: unit_tests
    displayName: Unit Tests
    dependsOn: build_environment
    strategy:
      maxParallel: 2
    steps:
      - bash: conda activate build_env
```

The last step `- bash: conda activate build_env` fails on me with the following error

```
Script contents:
conda activate build_env
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/d5af1b5c-9135-4984-ab16-72b82c91c329.sh

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.


##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Bash
```

How can I active conda? seems the path is wrong so that it is unable to find conda.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to
>   use 'conda activate'.

Here the issue is your script is run in a sub-shell, but `conda`hasn't been initialized in this sub-shell.

You need change your **active** script as：

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
        conda activate build_env
    displayName: Active
```

---

In addition, please do not split the `Add PATH`, `create environment` and `active the environment` into different jobs.

For Azure devops pipeline, `agent job` is the basic unit of the pipeline running process and each agent job has its own independent running environment and work logic.

For more detailed, you were using **Hosted agent** to apply your scripts in this issue scenario.

While there's one agent job starts to run, our pool system will **assign** an VM to this agent job. And, this VM will be **recycled** back once the agent job finished. When next agent job start to run , a completely new VM will be **randomly** reassign.

`dependsOn` can only share files and pass variables between jobs. It can not keep the VM continued in next job.

I believe you should be able to guess what problem you are going to encounter. Yes, even you can succeed to apply that `activate` script, you will continue face another `error: Could not find conda environment: build_env`. That's because the environment which is using  by this `activate` script is **a brand new vm**, the VM that previous `build_environment` job used has been recycled by the system.

So, do not split the create environment and activate into 2 agent jobs:

```
  - job: build_environment
    displayName: Build Environment
    dependsOn: pre_build_setup
    steps:
      - script: conda env create --file environment.yml --name build_env
        displayName: Create Anaconda environment
      - script: conda env list
        displayName:  environment installation verification
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
            conda activate build_env
        displayName: Active
```

Comment: Why does `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"` work but `conda init bash` fails?

Comment: Do you know the equivalent of `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"` on windows?

Comment: Use `-bash:` instead of `-script:`, then `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"` will work on windows too. just a workaound, not actual solution. @CiaranWelsh

Comment: Interesting. Think in the end I made sure I started every script with a call to `/full/path/to/conda init && . ~/.bashrc` (or windows equivalent)

Comment: This is rediculous. I've been scratching my head on how to do this properly for the last 3 years. No robust flow, just 'workarounds'.

Answer (score 1):

There's one more approach [proposed by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/anaconda?view=azure-devops&tabs=ubuntu#install-packages-from-anaconda) which seems to be more robust.

In every step where you want the environment to be activated, you should run

```
source $CONDA/bin/activate <myEnv>
```

or just

```
source activate <myEnv>
```

if you've already added `$CONDA/bin` to the PATH variable. You may check the link above to find examples for Ubuntu, macOS and Windows.

In your case it would look as follows:

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: source activate build_env
    displayName: Active
```

**Important note:** as for now, if you pass the name of the environment to `activate` script, the environment must be created in the same job. However, if you're using prefix (i.e. path to the environment directory), it doesn't matter.