# An azure hosted ubuntu agent adds conda to path, evals conda shell, creates/activates conda environment - finally attempts a pip install but fails

Tags: python, azure-devops, pip, conda

I use echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin" to add conda to path based on this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/anaconda?view=azure-devops&tabs=ubuntu-18-04

I use eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)" to use the correct shell based on this SO article: [Fail to active conda in Azure DevOps pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271364/fail-to-active-conda-in-azure-devops-pipeline)

I use conda to create and activate an environment.
I use pip to install a local package.
The package installation fails with error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/pip-req-build-2i5ffych/setup.py", line 75, in generate_repo_version
branch = line.strip().split(" ")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Here is some version information about the system:

```
Linux fv-az92-11 5.8.0-1041-azure #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 20 20:41:09 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Conda path:

```
CONDA:  /usr/share/miniconda
```

```
$CONDA/bin/conda info
     active environment : None
       user config file : /home/vsts/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=5.8.0=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /usr/share/miniconda  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /usr/share/miniconda/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /usr/share/miniconda/pkgs
                          /home/vsts/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /usr/share/miniconda/envs
                          /home/vsts/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.9.5 Linux/5.8.0-1041-azure ubuntu/20.04.3 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1001:121
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

```
pip --version

pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

```
which pip

/usr/bin/pip
```

```
/usr/share/miniconda/bin/pip --version

pip 21.1.3 from /usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Note that pip appears in two location and is pegged to python3.8 and python3.9 respectively.

A part of the problem is that I want to run my pipeline using python3.7 so I use the following entry in the azure-pipelines.yml file:

```
jobs:
  - job:
    displayName: ubuntu-latest
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    strategy:
      matrix:
        Python37:
          python.version: '3.7'
```

...as is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops

What other magic must I use beyond indicating that I want python3.7?
Can python3.9 and python3.8 be completely removed?  That seems hacky and cumbersome.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `UsePythonVersion@0` task to indicate the expected python version?

Comment: The problem was in the setup.py file, not in the pipeline configuration yml.  We were using the git repo's head when we generate the package.  We were expecting an output like `ref: refs/heads/master` but the output in azure looks like `ffe9cba521f00d7f60e3e2845072238635edb451` so I have to suppose that there is an api call in the azure pipeline that returns the objectId instead of the text as is indicated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#refs-heads